# Synology Docker UrBackup can't delete folder => Operation not permitted

Tags: docker, directory, synology

on a DS415+ I installed the Docker package and ran UrBackup.
Since the disk space on Volume1 was running low, I copied Docker and UrBackup to Volume2.

Then I deleted all Docker and UrBackup files on Volume1.

But I can't delete the /volume1/docker/urbackup/testA54hj5luZtlorr494/A folder.

I've already tried:

```
# chmod 777 A/
# chown root:root A/
# lsattr 
---------------- ./A
# sudo rm -r /A
rm: cannot remove ‘A/’: Operation not permitted
```

Now my shell knowledge is at an end and googling has not helped me any more.

I hope for your tips to get my system clean again.

Thx Max

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Learned something again:

Directory A cannot be deleted because it is not a directory.

It's a btrfs subvolume
It can be deleted with

```
# sudo btrfs subvolume delete /volume1/docker/urbackup/testA54hj5luZtlorr494/A
```

first i got the error

```
ERROR: cannot delete '/volume1/docker/urbackup/testA54hj5luZtlorr494/A': Device or resource busy
```

This could be avoided by stopping the container.

Maybe it will help someone ...

Comment: I even had to execute the above command with sudo (before `btrfs`...). My first attempt resulted in `ERROR: cannot delete '/volume2/docker/urbackup-server/backups/testA54hj5luZtlorr494/A': Operation not permitted`. With sudo the result and finally a removed /A/ was confirmed with `Delete subvolume (no-commit): '/volume2/docker/urbackup-server/backups/testA54hj5luZtlorr494/A`